# A non-unital commutative ring with infinite elements such that each element $a$ satisfies $ab =0$ for infinitely many $b$'s

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Beside the usual rules for non-unital commutative ring (that is, a ring without multiplicative identity) $R$, I want $R$ to satisfy the following:

$ab = 0$ for each element $a$ and there are infinitely many elements $b$ in the ring that satisfies $ab = 0$. Also for each possible $b$, let us label it as $b_1, b_2, ...$ and so on. Then $b_1 b_2 = b_1 b_3 = ... = b_2 b_3 = b_2 b_4 = ... = b_3 b_4 =....= 0$. For each $b_1$, there does not exist $c$ that satisfies $b_1 c = 0$ other than $a$ and $b_i$'s. There exists infinitely many such $a$'s.
Also, for every such $a$, there exists infitely many $c$ such that $ac \neq 0$.

Does such ring exist? If so, can ring operation $(+,\cdot)$ can be represented as arithmetic operation?

By the way, the trivial case where every $ab = 0$ is excluded.

Comment: *By the way, the trivial case where every ab=0 is excluded.*  This is fairly important.  So, should we say that $ab = 0$ if and only if $a = b$, or is it sufficient to have a single $a^2 \neq 0$?

Comment: Your title question makes sense, but the further I get into your second paragraph, the more I don't understand what you want. You appear to want an infinite rng where every element's right annihilator is infinite, where a countable subset of each of these right annihilators has sequential pairs annihilating each other, with another restriction on what *can't* annihilate them, and you want infinitely many elements that don't annihlate each $a$.

Comment: And doyou really mean "for each $b_1$? or you meant $b_i$?

Comment: Another try at understanding what you want: Each element has is annihilated by infinitely many elements, and not annihilated by infinitely many elements. Furthermore for each element, there is a countable sequence of things annihilating that element, each of which is annihilated by the next term of the sequence, but which is not annihilated by anything outside of the sequence or the element $a$.

Comment: @Kampas This really needs to be clarified before anyone can make any headway.

Comment: @rschwieb Your understanding is indeed my intention.